# Introductory clause with a question

Tags: tenses

Please help me solve this.

Why would him saying, "She is ugly," offend John?

or

Why would he saying, "She is ugly," offend John?

Comment: Why would his saying or him saying, but not he saying (except if you don't care about grammar.)

Comment: Subjects of gerund-participial clauses are either accusative or genitive, i.e. "him" or "his".

Answer (score 3):

Surprisingly, the correct construction is neither of the options you suggest. Because "saying" is a noun, the action is possessed by someone; therefore, you should use "his."

Why would his saying "She is ugly" offend John?

Edit by Michael since I don’t yet have enough reputation to post a comment:

Let’s try again by substituting a proper noun in the sentence and see what that give us:

Why would Charlie saying “She is ugly” offend John?

Why would Charlie’s saying “She is ugly” offend John?

“Saying” is a participial form of the verb “say”; hence, it is a gerund in noun form, i.e. an action; therefore: Why would Charlie’s [action] offend John?

Comment: Thank you so much. That makes sense. My 16-year-old daughter and I often correct each other's grammar. She and I had a very serious debate on this one. I thought it would be "he," but I stand corrected. Best regards, Trish

Comment: "Him saying she was ugly offended John." would be acceptable in speech. [I thought] him saying that was offensive.

Comment: No, Michael, "saying" is a verb here, not a noun. The reported speech is syntactically a complement of "saying". Nouns don't take reported speech as complement.

Comment: @TrishElking Sorry, Trish, but Michael has got it wrong. In your example, "saying" is not a noun but a verb, which can have either accusative "him" or genitive "his" as subject. Please see my comment above this one.

Comment: @billj Really. I have a plaque on my wall at home. On that plaque is a saying of mine. (It's something I say often.)  That saying reads "She is ugly." John came to my house one day and saw my saying. *Why would my saying "She is ugly" offend John?* But there is a distinction between the question and this answer. The question uses speech tags. This answer does not. One is a verb, the other is a noun. It depends on if the original poster was actually talking about a verb or was talking about a noun and used speech tags anyway.

Comment: @JasonBassford "Saying" here has the syntactic properties of a verb, not a noun. For example, it can be modified by the adverb "occasionally", but not by the adjective "occasional" -- adverbs don't modify nouns. And it has the narrative 'she is ugly' as complement, but nouns don't take such complements

Comment: @JasonBassford I agree with your point. "Saying" could be a noun as in "adage," rather than a participle functioning as a gerund.  In the original sentence there was a comma after "saying," which would indicate reported speech. In Michael's sentence  the quote marks could simply be emphasis, as quote marks enclose the title of a poem or song. In either case "his" is correct.

Comment: @Zan700 The salient interpretation of "She is ugly" is that of direct reported speech functioning as complement of "saying", thus the latter is a reporting verb, not a noun. Further the OP asked whether the pronoun should be "him" or "he, (not "his") which would indicate that they intended "saying" to be verb. Note though, that genitive "his" can also be the subject of the OP's sentence.

Comment: OP's don't generally ask questions as arcane as this where my saying is an adage or motto unless they indicate it. So, the reading is very improbable.

Comment: @Lambie True regarding the OP, but I was responding to Jason's comment. I would like to know if the comma in the OP's original sentence would make the arcane interpretation grammatically impossible.

Comment: "Commas are mistakes"// Why would my saying "Commas are mistakes." offend anyone?  The commas are not needed to quote someone within an utterance. Compare: Why would  his saying [David's truism] "Narcissists are nincompoops" offend John? In my opinion the commas are not relevant.

Comment: @Zan700 Why do you persist in arguing about the status of "saying". As Lambie says, its analysis as a noun is very improbable, so confusing the OP like this is just not on.

Comment: @BillJ  John said, "The game will start at midnight." is a direct quotation. John said that the game will start at midnight. is an indirect quotation. John said, "That the game will start at midnight is unlikely." is a direct quotation.John said that the game will start at midnight is unlikely. is an indirect quotation. John said "That the game will start at midnight." is what?

Answer (score 0):

Brilliant question. In ambiguous sentences like this, go with the most natural flow and your first example is the most natural one. Let's break down the sentence and find which is the subject. Which is the subject here? "She is ugly" is not the subject here. ["She is ugly" said by him] in other words, [Him saying "she is ugly"] is the subject here. If you want to rewrite this for clarity, "His comment about how ugly she looked offended him" would be the correct form.

Comment: I'd say the subject of the sentence is "Why would him saying, 'She is ugly'.

Comment: A wh-question cannot be considered part of the subject. The sentence would still be meaningful without it, so it it is not part of the subject. Some reference here: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/questions-and-negative-sentences/questions-wh-questions

Comment: In that case what function in the sentence does ""why would" have?

Comment: "Why would" modifies the statement into a question

Comment: I would say, it is more of a rule that why, what, are where are not considered part of the subject. A subject should answer a question like, who, what or which. A question couldn't be an answer to that question.

Comment: Actually, it would be better to analyse "why" as an adjunct of cause. That would accord with the normal function of "why" which is to question the reason or purpose, where the answer would be "Because ...". The subject is then "would him saying, "She is ugly"

Answer (score 0):

Let me elaborate on a comment I made that was related to Michael's answer but  not understood.

Although the commas used in the punctuation of your example sentences indicate actual speech (they are used along with verbal speech tags), another interpretation is that [**saying**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/saying) can be taken as a noun:

> something said; *especially* : ADAGE

For the sake of my answer, I'm going to use the word *motto* instead.

The correct way of constructing a sentence of this type is:

> Why would **his** motto "She is ugly" offend John?

Neither of your other constructions would be grammatical:

> Why would **him** motto "She is ugly" offend John?
>   Why would **he** motto "She is ugly" offend John?

If you are using **saying** as a verb, an instance of uttered speech, then look to the other answers.

But if you are actually talking about a phrase, motto, adage, or **saying** when used as a conceptual noun, then this answer should provide the pronoun.

To give a [specific example](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/10413209208406460?journalCode=uasp20) (emphasis mine):

> Leonardo da Vinci is supposed to supposed to have said: "Unhappy the master who is not surpassed by his disciples," and I find **his** saying applies to academic research as well—one is always hoping that what one did is going to be improved upon by someone else.

[Or](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2252298?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents) (emphasis mine):

> This remark of his—that in applying the same word to several instances we mark a family resemblance and not the possession of something in common—was connected with a point which on on occasion at the Cambridge Moral Sciences Club he expressed in the words, "We have the idea that the meaning of a word is an object." This is connected with **his** saying "Don't ask for the meaning, ask for the use", recommended at the Moral Sciences Club as a supplement to "The meaning of a statement is the method of its verification".

Comment: Who would ever say that was a motto? It's about speech.

Comment: @Lambie The word *motto* is just one synonym which I used to illustrate the point about the particular sense of the word. I have updated my answer with some specific examples where **saying** *is* a (possessed) noun and where neither **him** nor **he** would apply.